# IntelliSense & .NetCore

Tags: .net-core, intellisense

I've been using .NetCore for some smaller projects and I generally love it, but there are a few issues, of which one has been irritating me quite a bit:

In this example a lot of the configuration stuff uses extension methods to hang extra features off of Json, Command Line, Object Binding etc... In these cases all of which live in separate packages. When you see some code examples which typically include one or more of them you naturally copy them into a project to try them out, giving you compile errors when you try to build them.

Asking VS for guidance (pressing good old Ctrl Dot), doesn't help and so you have to search for the relevant packages you need followed by more searches in Nuget installing each one as required.

So my question is (Drum Roll Please) am I missing something or is there a tool/setting or extension that can give me suggestions based on exported extension methods on Nuget's public packages when you press Ctrl Dot on the error much like suggestions on missing namespaces?

Regards
Lee

Comment: It is a chicken-and-egg problem, IntelliSense cannot help you when it doesn't know where the extension method came from.  Object Browser is as good as it gets.  Being a bit selective about what kind of wonky libraries you commit to is advisable, they have a non-zero cost.

Comment: With a site full of metadata like https://www.fuget.org/ it is possible to extend Roslyn or ReSharper to suggest extension methods and missing packages. However, you probably would hit performance issues (for example, a dot can yields too many results). So generally speaking, do more and train your mind. You don't have too many extension methods/packages to remember usually.

Comment: Hi Lex, It's not so much "training", my mind...even if I did know the package names off by heart, you still have to find them in Nuget adding them individually. Admittedly not a major hassle but still wasted time that could be automated. I think Zoxive gave the best answer hence the tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting netcoreapp2.1 you can use the metapackage which will include all of "supported" packages from Microsoft.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1